# Update values in minutes on x axis of chart

Tags: c#

In my C# application im using a point chart.On y axis the chart needs points like 10,20,30 etc.. to update. And x axis having time values (minutes) to update.

I found an example in google, but in that example having only values on X axis and Y axis.How to update time instead of values? . Please refer my code below,

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        chart1.Series.Clear();
        var series1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series
        {
            Name = "Series1",
            Color = System.Drawing.Color.Green,
            IsVisibleInLegend = false,
            IsXValueIndexed = true,
            ChartType = SeriesChartType.Point
        };

        this.chart1.Series.Add(series1);

        for (int i=0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            series1.Points.AddXY(i, f(i));
        }
        chart1.Invalidate();
    }

    private double f(int i)
    {
        var f1 = 59894 - (8128 * i) + (262 * i * i) - (1.6 * i * i * i);
        return f1;
    }
```

If it possible please update the time in this code itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the line:

```
IsXValueIndexed=true;
```

And add a line:

```
chart1.ChartArea1.AxisX.Title= "Minutes";
```

Comment: ,This line of code is giving title to the x-axis.Is there any way to update the value as time.That means after 60 minutes,it should be 1 hour.Like wise I need to add every 5 minutes in my x-axis.

Comment: Set `series1.XValueType=ChartValueType.Time` and when you add a point use `series.Points.AddXY(new DateTime().AddMinutes(i), f(i))` and change axis title to "Hours and minutes" or "Time"